# Is there a way to sync audio messages in iMessage between iPhone and Mac?

Tags: iphone

My text messages are automatically synced between my iPhone and Mac. Is there a way to get my audio messages to sync too? Sometimes when I look back in a message thread it's hard to follow because either I or the other has sent an audio message instead of texting.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it! I needed to check this box in order to make it work:

[image: "Enable Messages in iCloud"]

Go to Messages in your Mac. Go to Preferences in the Messages menu. Click the iMessage tab. Click "Enable Messages in iCloud". Voila!